# DIY TDA2822N computer microphone

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, microphone, diy

I am using the following circuit to make a computer microphone.
The "speaker" component is the computer's microphone input. The problem with this circuit is that somehow I can hear capacitors discharging or something similar https://vocaroo.com/i/s1U2NhEnlQaa. I have also started to believe that some kind of **aliens** are trying to communicate with me when I am touching the board https://vocaroo.com/i/s0wLsUYS8Rym. How can I "cut" these peaks and prevent aliens interrupting to my signal?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA8V7T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Did you build it on a breadboard?

Comment: Ouch. Let's get quantitative. What is the input voltage range of the mic, what is the gain of the amplifier, and what is the expected input voltage range of the computer's microphone input?

Comment: 1.  The pops sound like bad connections - very possible (and expected, even) on a breadboard.  2.  The "alien sounds" are either oscillations in the circuit itself or else radio intereference being picked up by the wires in the circuit.  Breadboards contribute to both of those - oscillations because breadboards tend to have capacitance between pins and picking up radio signals because the wires used on breadboards can be long enough to act a antennas.  The amplifier has enough amplification to make low level oscillations or interference seem very loud.

Comment: WHy is that pot connected where it is

Comment: @JRE I have built it on a prototyping board(you know the one with the holes), I am still working on the pcb version, I wanted to make sure that it is working first. So you are saying that if I print it on a pcb is gonna improve the quality of the sound?

Comment: I'm saying that having built it on a breadboard would explain why you are having some of the problems. If you soldered things to a perf board, the you shouldn't have as much trouble.

Comment: @JRE It is soldered to a perf board but it still has wires

Comment: I changed the position of the output wire so it want be next to the ground ones and the quality is increased really much! I still have some small pop sounds but I think that the pcb version will make it even better, I will keep it unanswered for a bit more since it is possible that someone will type a better solution

Comment: Also, what did you do with the  other half of the chip. Leaving it floating would be a bad thing,

Comment: @Trevor why would it be?

Comment: @DrunkProgrammer because left floating it is free to pick up and amplify any RF noise in your general neighborhood which will couple through to the side you are using.

Comment: @Trevor even if I insulate the pins?

Comment: @DrunkProgrammer even if insulated. You need to tie the unused inputs to ground, or one to ground and one to the rail.

Comment: Why a power amplifier ? Any rail-to-rail single-supply opamp would do a much better job.

Comment: @altai TDA2822M was the only amplifier I had

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Carefully placing the wires would fix the problem just make it should that no positive or output wire is near to ground wires even if they are insulated